# I get Compiler Error Message: CS1061: when i click a report button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried adding files to update the application to generate new excel reports on my web application hosted on IIS 7 but i get the error below when i click to generate on the application

Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message:

CS1061:

```
'ASP.reportmonthlyreturns_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'btnGenerator_Click'
 and no extension method 'btnGenerator_Click' accepting a first argument of type 
'ASP.reportmonthlyreturns_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an 
assembly reference?)
```

Source Error:

```
Line 36:             SelectCommand="SELECT distinct year(departure_berth) as year FROM va_voyage_master_tb">
Line 37:         </asp:SqlDataSource>
Line 38:         <asp:Button ID="btnGenerator" runat="server" Text="Generate Report" 
Line 39:         class="button round blue image-right ic-right-arrow" onclick="btnGenerator_Click" 
Line 40:          />    


Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\VoyageApplication\ReportMonthlyReturns.aspx    Line: 38
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your markup (.aspx) page contains a reference to an event that doesn't exist in your code behind page (.cs).

**Check the casing on the OnClick property declaration. It should be Pascal cased: "OnClick".**

Based on your markup,

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGenerator" runat="server" OnClick="btnGenerator_Click" />
```

your code should contain something along the lines of this:

```
protected void btnGenerator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // logic here
}
```

Is there any chance that you changed the OnClick event property within your markup or code behind? The two must match.

Comment: if you elaborate more, I might +1

Comment: Not much else I can possibly add. Does the event signature match the declaration name? Is the casing correct on your markup? (It doesn't appear to be.)

Comment: Please i am sending you my code behind and .asp code for the report.